# Combinatorics IOQM

Tags: combinatorics

A $12 \times 12 $ board is divided into $144$ unit squares by drawing lines parallel to the sides. Two rooks placed on two unit squares are said to be non attacking if they are not in the same column or same row. Find the least number $N$ such that if$ N$ rooks are placed on the unit squares, one rook per square, we can always find $7$ rooks such that no two are attacking each other.

Comment: Hii, welcome to MSE. What have you tried so far? Please edit your question and provide context. Show us your work, on what step you got stuck and need help, your thoughts about the problem, etc. Have a look at [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) text to know how to ask a good question here.